# Can I manually delete EventCache entries from the Sharepoint database?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm trying to empty out the eventcache table because it has grown to a size where it's causing storage-related errors. The event retention period was originally 120 days, and I lowered it to 1 day (because most entries have been generated recently). I manually ran the Change Log timer service several times, but it is not removing anything from the eventcache.

Unless there is another way to clear this table, I'm thinking of just deleting them all directly via SQL, but I'm worried this might cause problems because I went around Sharepoint procedures. Is there any risk or can I just delete all these rows myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't, as it would mean that your SharePoint farm becomes unsupportable from a Microsoft standpoint. You can find more information in the article below:

[Unsupported and supported SharePoint Server database changes](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/unsupported-and-supported-sharepoint-database-changes)